# in wordpress, a valid callback for cp_admin_init and _canonical_charset

Tags: callback, wordpress, warnings

I'm using `WordPress 3.5` with child-theme of `Twenty Eleven 1.5`. Suddenly I'm getting following Warning,

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'cp_admin_init' was given in /home/templ/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 406

Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, '_canonical_charset' was given in /home/templ/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 173
```

I'm using following plugins:

1. download-manager 2.3.9
2. wordpress-seo 1.4.7
3. wp-pagenavi 2.83

Some more points:

**1)** If I'm giving **mysite.com** it's giving above 2 line warning. If I give **www.mysite.com**, the following line also include,

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/templ/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:406) in /home/templ/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 876
```

**2)** If I give **mysite.com/wp-admin/** or **www.mysite.com/wp-admin/**, It's giving 1st warning and 3rd warning.

**3)** If I goto **www.mysite.com/wp-login.php**, It's giving following 5 warning.

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'cp_admin_init' was given in /home/templ/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 406

Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, '_canonical_charset' was given in /home/templ/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 173

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/templ/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:406) in /home/templ/public_html/wp-login.php on line 368

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/templ/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:406) in /home/templ/public_html/wp-login.php on line 380

Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'wp_authenticate_spam_check' was given in /home/templ/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 173
```

**4)** If I give correct username and password, it's not going to login. giving following problem,

```
ERROR: Invalid username or incorrect password.
ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.
```

I'm trying to find solution. I can't. Can any-one help me?

Comment: You install a recent plug in ? what browser do you use ? Your server have upgrade your php version ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a corrupted install.  So you have a few options to fix this:

- Attempt to get logins operational again and doing an upgrade though the `wp-admin`: Explained Below.
- Do a manual Update: http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update

**But First: Make a Backup**

Please be sure to backup your install! Before proceeding: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Backups

**Getting Logins Working: Masking the symptoms**

First I would disable debugging output because that should fix most of these issues.  When a warning occurs in Wordpress, PHP starts writing the response body and closes the header section of the response. This means that whenever Wordpress tries to add another header after the original warning was raised, PHP will raise another warning:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/templ/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:406) in /home/templ/public_html/wp-login.php on line 380
```

So if we disable debugging then we should be able to mask the symptoms. This is a quick patch for a larger problem that we will have to solve with an in-place upgrade

**To Disable Debugging**

Ensure that the following constants exist and are set correctly is in your `wp-config.php` file

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

and

```
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

Now you should be able to login to your site as an administrator without errors.

**Disable your Plugins**

Disable all your plugins in `Plugins -> Installed Plugins`  This is imperative so that we can make sure that the update goes smoothly.

**Do an Update**

Go to `Dashboard -> Updates` and click either `Update Now` or `Re-install Now`

**Reactivate your Plugins**

Reactivate all your plugins in `Plugins -> Installed Plugins` and update them if necessary.

**That's It**

That's the process for reinstalling Wordpress.  The key here is that you have Debugging enabled on a production site which is not good.  You should always have `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` set to `false` in a production environment.